# Why -[UILabel setText] causes instant relayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have complex `UICollectionViewCell` with about 10 labels on it. So I need to fill them up with data before displaying, so I do it in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method. Labels are not fixed-width and there are some non-required (priority less than 1000) constraints, so some labels can be shrinked.
Each `setText` call causes `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`, which I think is fine to mark as invalid to cause layout to happen on next layout pass, but I was very surprised it does some extra work with constraints, so scrolling gets really slow.

[image: instruments screenshot]

Why it does this extra work? Is there any way to do it only one on my command after I set all the label texts or on next layout pass?

Scroll is very slow on iOS 6, iOS 8+ works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no answer "why" it behaves like mentioned, but I found workaround: I subclass `UILabel` and use it whenever I know I don't need intrinsic sized. This saved 50% of time spend on recalculating layout.

```
@interface NoIntrinsicSizeLabel : UILabel
@end
@implementation NoIntrinsicSizeLabel
- (void)invalidateIntrinsicContentSize {
    return;
}
@end
```